# How can I find out if there are unsupported characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, c#

I use the following javascript code to detect unsupported characters in a string.

```
VerifyTextUnicodeCharacters("My_string");

function VerifyTextUnicodeCharacters(text)
{
var notSupportArray = new Array();
for (var i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var charCode = text.charCodeAt(i);
    if ((charCode == 33) || (charCode == 35) || (charCode == 38) || (charCode >= 40 && charCode <= 42) || (charCode == 46) || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 91) || (charCode == 93) || (charCode == 95) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 123) || (charCode == 125))
    {
        
    }
    else
    {
        notSupportArray.push(charCode);
    }
}

if (notSupportArray.length == 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```

How can I do exactly the same thing in C#?

Comment: A string is a `char[]` in C# so basically in exactly the same way. What problem are you having with the C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just consider string like an array of char:

```
bool VerifyTextUnicodeCharacters(text)
{

    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        var charCode = (int)text[i];
        :
        :
    }
  :
  :
}
```

To translate notsupportArray, you could use List, Array or Queue, here i am using [Queue](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-queue): (Queue is FIFO (First In First Out) collection)

```
Queue<int> notsupportArray = new Queue<int>();
```

The equivalent of `push` is `Enqueue`:

```
notsupportArray.Enqueue(charCode);
```

and the number of items in Queue is:

```
notsupportArray.Count
```

Comment: How can I translate var notSupportArray = new Array(); to C#? I have tried it with string[] notSupportArray; but it's not working.

Comment: i have completed my answer

Comment: Don't see the need for any kind of collection, let alone a queue. The whole method could just be `return text.Any(c => IsUnsupportedCharacter(c))` where `bool IsUnsupportedCharacter(Char c)` does the check: as soon as an invalid character is found, there's no point continuing.

Comment: that depends if he wants to keep or not the unwanted characters...following the sample, he wants..